# Finding maximal elements of partially ordered sets

Tags: graphs-and-networks, sets, subset

I am dealing with [partially ordered sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) $\Gamma$, which I represent as directed graphs with an edge going from $a$ to $b$ if $a \leq b$ in $\Gamma$. For example the following graph,

```
\[CapitalGamma] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 10, 12, 24};
edges = Apply[DirectedEdge,Select[Tuples[\[CapitalGamma], 2], 
   Mod[#[[2]], #[[1]]] == 0 &], {1}];
Graph[\[CapitalGamma], edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

which looks like the following.

[image]

This is the poset with elements $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 10, 12, 24\}$, ordered by division. In this set the [maximal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements) elements are $7,10$ and $24$. Is there some clever way in Mathematica to find a list of maximal elements directly from a graph?

Comment: You can generate your graph with a one-liner: `RelationGraph[Divisible, \[CapitalGamma]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
Γ = {2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 10, 12, 24};

g = SimpleGraph[RelationGraph[Divisible, Γ], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
sources[g_?GraphQ] := Pick[VertexList[g], VertexInDegree[g], 0]

sources[g]
(* {7, 10, 24} *)
```

Comment: Someone might point out ``GraphComputation`SourceVertexList``, but it does exactly the same thing as `sources` above.  IGraph/M also has `IGSourceVertexList` and `IGSinkVertexList`, implemented roughly this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the maximal elements and don't need the graph, you could use `` Internal`ListMin ``. `` Internal`ListMin `` finds the minimal elements of a set of lists using a component-wise partial order (see [(805)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103004/45431)):

```
maximal[list_] := Module[{p, e},
    p=FactorInteger[LCM@@list][[All, 1]];
    e=IntegerExponent[#, p]& /@ list;
    Sort @ Map[Times@@(p^#)&] @ -Internal`ListMin[-e]
]
```

For your example:

```
maximal[{2,3,5,7,6,8,10,12,24}]
```

> {7, 10, 24}

A comparison with the [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph)-base approach using a larger list:

```
list = RandomSample[Range[10^4], 1000];

r1 = maximal[list]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = sources[
    SimpleGraph[RelationGraph[Divisible, list], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
]; //AbsoluteTiming

Sort @ r1 === Sort @ r2
```

> {0.175122, Null}
>
> {1.45297, Null}
>
> True